# Rails appears as not installed even though it is installed

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails.  After finally getting my environment to work properly with RVM 2.0.0 rails 4.0.5, all of a sudden rails disappeared and I keep getting the message: Rails is not currently installed on this system...

When I quit terminal, reopen it, and type:

```
$ rails v
```

It shows `4.0.5`

However, as soon as I change directory into my rails app and check the rails version I get the message that rails is not installed.

Any idea what's going here?

Comment: check for an .rvmrc file switching your gemset / ruby version. Sounds like your default ruby has Rails but your project's ruby/gemset does not.

Comment: try: restart terminal

Comment: Does `bundle exec rails` work?

Comment: Restarting the terminal doesn't help.  When I am in the root directory $ rails v => 4.0.5, when I'm in the app directory no rails.

Comment: What do `rvm gemset list_all` gives you ?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `rvm` you have multiple versions of ruby installed. You select which one you want like this:

```
rvm use 2.0
```

or

```
rvm use 2.1
```

You can also specify a ruby version in a `.ruby-version` file in a directory. Then when you change to that directory in the terminal, RVM will switch versions for you.

Each version of ruby has its own set of installed gems. Rails is a gem.

Ergo, when you installed rails, you were in your default ruby version (probably the one build-in on your system). When you change directory to your rails application, RVM is kicking in to switch to the correct ruby version for you. But you don't have rails installed in that version.

So the solution is to switch to the directory for your rails app and run:

```
bundle install
```

This will install your gem bundle for your application, including the rails gems, and it will do it into the correct ruby version.

Comment: Yup, that did the trick.  I also found out that the Gemfile contained the following: #ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0 which is different than the gemset name I created for this project.  I assume that updating this line to the correct gemset will prevent from this issue to happen in the future.

Comment: @user2573222 I suggest using the .ruby-gemset as well as .ruby-version for compatibility with other version managers such as rbenv